# Como obter múltiplos JSONObject com a mesma key?

Tags: java, json

Basicamente, eu tenho este JSON:

```
{"gameId":467366059,"mapId":11,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","gameType":"MATCHED_GAME","gameQueueConfigId":4,"participants":[{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":14,"championId":157,"profileIconId":588,"summonerName":"MEDAUMASKINCOPY","bot":false,"**summonerId**":2833743,"runes":[{"count":6,"runeId":5247},{"count":3,"runeId":5251},{"count":9,"runeId":5289},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":1,"runeId":5337},{"count":2,"runeId":5412}],"masteries":[{"rank":1,"masteryId":4111},{"rank":4,"masteryId":4112},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4122},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4131},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4132},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4134},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4141},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4142},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4144},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4212},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4221},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232}]},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":11,"spell2Id":4,"championId":254,"profileIconId":550,"summonerName":"copy","bot":false,"**summonerId**":2883696,"runes":[{"count":9,"runeId":5247},{"count":3,"runeId":5290},{"count":6,"runeId":5295},{"count":9,"runeId":5315},{"count":3,"runeId":5335}],"masteries":[{"rank":1,"masteryId":4111},{"rank":4,"masteryId":4113},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4122},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4131},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4132},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4134},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4141},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4142},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4213},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4214},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4224},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232}]},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"championId":85,"profileIconId":23,"summonerName":"Yzy Zikaa","bot":false,"**summonerId**":1356728,"runes":[{"count":1,"runeId":5273},{"count":9,"runeId":5297},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":3,"runeId":5357},{"count":8,"runeId":5402}],"masteries":[{"rank":4,"masteryId":4112},{"rank":4,"masteryId":4113},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4123},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4131},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4133},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4143},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4154},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4212},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4213},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232}]},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":7,"spell2Id":4,"championId":104,"profileIconId":608,"summonerName":"Gunex","bot":false,"summonerId":653768,"runes":[{"count":9,"runeId":5245},{"count":9,"runeId":5290},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":3,"runeId":5335}],"masteries":[{"rank":1,"masteryId":4111},{"rank":4,"masteryId":4112},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4121},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4122},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4131},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4132},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4134},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4142},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4213},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4221},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232}]},{"teamId":100,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":3,"championId":117,"profileIconId":660,"summonerName":"uunk","bot":false,"**summonerId**":633003,"runes":[{"count":9,"runeId":5273},{"count":9,"runeId":5298},{"count":9,"runeId":5316},{"count":3,"runeId":5357}],"masteries":[{"rank":2,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4212},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4221},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4311},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4312},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4313},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4322},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4324},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4331},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4334},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4341},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4342},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4353},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4362}]},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":14,"spell2Id":4,"championId":25,"profileIconId":585,"summonerName":"Zigoto","bot":false,"**summonerId**":458902,"runes":[{"count":9,"runeId":5273},{"count":9,"runeId":5289},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":3,"runeId":5357}],"masteries":[{"rank":4,"masteryId":4113},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4121},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4123},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4131},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4133},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4134},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4143},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4154},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4312},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4313},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4322},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4324},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4334}]},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":11,"championId":60,"profileIconId":28,"summonerName":"TakeruX","bot":false,"**summonerId**":1513707,"runes":[{"count":9,"runeId":5289},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":3,"runeId":5357},{"count":9,"runeId":5402}],"masteries":[{"rank":4,"masteryId":4113},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4114},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4123},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4124},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4133},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4134},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4143},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4154},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4213},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4214},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4224},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232}]},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"championId":150,"profileIconId":518,"summonerName":"52GO Jabiraka","bot":false,"**summonerId**":531086,"runes":[{"count":8,"runeId":5245},{"count":1,"runeId":5251},{"count":9,"runeId":5289},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":1,"runeId":5335},{"count":2,"runeId":5343}],"masteries":[{"rank":4,"masteryId":4113},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4114},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4122},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4132},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4213},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4221},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4233},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4234},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4243},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4244},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4252},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4262}]},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":7,"championId":18,"profileIconId":718,"summonerName":"Reed x","bot":false,"**summonerId**":891096,"runes":[{"count":9,"runeId":5245},{"count":9,"runeId":5289},{"count":9,"runeId":5317},{"count":3,"runeId":5337}],"masteries":[{"rank":3,"masteryId":4112},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4114},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4122},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4124},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4131},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4132},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4134},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4141},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4142},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4144},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4151},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4152},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4162},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4212},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4221},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232}]},{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":3,"championId":267,"profileIconId":610,"summonerName":"SK Sheldon","bot":false,"**summonerId**":2982516,"runes":[{"count":1,"runeId":5251},{"count":8,"runeId":5257},{"count":9,"runeId":5297},{"count":5,"runeId":5315},{"count":4,"runeId":5317},{"count":1,"runeId":5345},{"count":2,"runeId":5357}],"masteries":[{"rank":2,"masteryId":4211},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4212},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4221},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4222},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4232},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4233},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4312},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4313},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4314},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4322},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4324},{"rank":3,"masteryId":4331},{"rank":2,"masteryId":4333},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4334},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4341},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4342},{"rank":1,"masteryId":4352}]}],"observers":{"encryptionKey":"dkGJf37jaGpYGYBhwbBaNcG9XvUKW9WQ"},"platformId":"BR1","bannedChampions":[{"championId":64,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":1},{"championId":238,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":2},{"championId":40,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":3},{"championId":103,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":4},{"championId":268,"teamId":100,"pickTurn":5},{"championId":55,"teamId":200,"pickTurn":6}],"gameStartTime":1423276435804,"gameLength":-126}
```

Recomendo visualização [nesse link](http://pastebin.com/TjjJ4jWk).

E dentro de tudo isso, eu preciso pegar todos os `summonerId`, que no caso são 10. Esse é o meu código, porém ele só pega o primeiro `summonerId` e ignora o restante:

```
Map json1 = (Map)parser.parse(matei);
JSONObject wtf1 = (JSONObject) json1;
JSONArray eat = (JSONArray) wtf1.get("participants");
JSONObject dash= (JSONObject) eat.iterator().next();
Long wtfbo = (Long) dash.get("summonerId");
System.out.println(wtfbo);
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que eu posso fazer pra conseguir pegar todos?

Comment: De onde você pegou as classes `JSONArray` e `JSONObject`? Qual é o tipo exato da variável `parser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente de onde você pegou as classes `JSONArray` e `JSONObject`, uma vez que há muitos projetos diferentes feitos independentemente por muitas pessoas diferentes que tem classes com estes nomes.

Entretanto, supondo que o seu código não gere nenhum erro de compilação, me parece que você está utilizando o `Iterator` de forma incorreta, apenas pegando o primeiro elemento dele ao invés de percorrê-lo. Então você poderia fazer assim:

```java
Map json1 = (Map) parser.parse(matei);
JSONObject wtf1 = (JSONObject) json1;
JSONArray eat = (JSONArray) wtf1.get("participants");
Iterator it = eat.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject dash = (JSONObject) it.next();
    Long wtfbo = (Long) dash.get("summonerId");
    System.out.println(wtfbo);
}
```

Comment: Poderia me dizer qual biblioteca é essa que possui o método `iterator`?

Comment: @rrnan Não sei. Por isso que eu disse "supondo que o seu código não gere nenhum erro de compilação".

Comment: O código funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>A classe que utilizo para manipular JSON não possui nenhum método `iterator`, ainda assim segue uma alternativa utilizando *loop* :</sup>

```
JSONArray array = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("participants");
int lenght = array.length();

for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++){
   JSONObject current = array.getJSONObject(i);
   System.out.println(current.get("summonerId")); // faz algo...
}
```

Testando como entrada o JSON que colocou junto a pergunta, a saída foram [esses números](http://pastebin.com/edSJ6QXE).