# Como separar uma string em várias em java?

Tags: java, json, string

O meu problema é basicamente o seguinte, eu tenho um código JSON que pega os dados a partir de uma URL, e me retorna isso (Os valores estão em Long)

```
528593
444218
5693595
2466912
2466435
```

Porém, ele me retorna isso em uma única variável (no caso, a "wtfbo"), e eu preciso dividir isso em uma string para cada uma para poder encaixar na interface que já tenho montada. No caso, eu estou utilizando esse código no momento

```
  [...]
  Iterator<?> it = eat.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
      JSONObject dash = (JSONObject) it.next();
      Long wtfb10 = (Long) dash.get("teamId");

  if(wtfb10==100){
           Long wtfbo = (Long) dash.get("summonerId");
            String play = (String) dash.get("summonerName");
            String ko = wtfbo.toString();
            System.out.println(ko);
 }}
 [...]
```

Alguma ideia?

//EDIT: Em resumo, o "Long wtfbo" vai retornar 5 summonerId diferente, só que tudo nele, eu preciso que ele retorne em 5 strings diferentes, sendo que cada uma tenha um summonerID.

Comment: Como é a estrutura do JSON?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TjjJ4jWk é idêntica a essa, e no caso, eu preciso pegar os summonersID/summonerName dos 10 jogadores.

Comment: No JSON que você mandou cada ID está um um objeto diferente. O que você quer dizer com "retorna isso em uma única variável"?

Comment: é que todas as 10 summonerId diferente, retornam tudo no "wtfbo"

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49838/como-obter-m%C3%BAltiplos-jsonobject-com-a-mesma-key

Answer (score 2):

Não posso comentar então... rs.
Não entendi ao certo se você que apenas os códigos dos "summonerId" ou os objetos dos participantes que contém esse atributo.

Para pegar um array com os objetos dos participantes você poderia fazer algo como o código abaixo.
Considerando o json que está no pastebin, para pegar os participantes:

```
JSONArray participantes = jsonData.getJSONArray("participants");
//manipula valores dos participantes
for (int i=0; i < participantes.length(); i++) {
    //participante no índice i
    JSONObject player = arrFilmes.getJSONObject(i);
    Long wtfbo = (Long) player.get("summonerId");
    ...
}
```

Então pegaria os dados de cada participante e poderia estruturar da forma que quisesse.
Espero que ajude em algo e boa sorte.

Comment: Até essa parte eu consigo, o problema é que ele retorna todos os valores de summonerId no "wtfbo", e eu precisaria que ele retornasse cada um em uma string diferente.

Comment: Porque não cria um List de String e vai adicionando? tipo
   List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
Aí, dentro do for, quando receber o "summonerId" faz assim:
   ids.add(summonerId);
Depois é só usar os valores da lista.

Comment: Fazendo desse jeito:                                     while (it.hasNext()) {
JSONObject dash = (JSONObject) it.next();
Long wtfb10 = (Long) dash.get("teamId");

if(wtfb10==100){
     
Long wtfbo = (Long) dash.get("summonerId");
ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
ids.add(wtfbo);
}                                                          e ele armazenou tudo no valor 0 da lista.

Comment: Crie o ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>(); fora do loop while, pois ele está sendo recriado a cada interação, por isso os valores 0 provavelmente..

Comment: Ele continua salvando todos os valores juntos no mesmo valor da lista.

Comment: Tenta imprimir o valor antes de adicionar na lista para ver se não está vindo tudo de uma vez só ou algo assim, porque em teoria é para funcionar.